# How to get the derivative based on the function?

Tags: derivatives

Based on $f(x) = x^2$, we know $f'(x) = 2x$.

If $x = y^2$

Then $f(y) = (y^2)^2 = y^4$, and $f'(y) = 4y^3$.

My question is if we only know

- $f'(x) = 2x$
- $x = y^2$

How to get $f'(y) = 4y^3$ ? Any hint or formula will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $f'$ is incorrect; it should be $2x$. And what are you looking for is called Chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: Oh that is what I need, I will fix my question too! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HongboMiao You're welcome :) The easy way to remember the formula is $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$, i.e. you revert the cancellation of $\mathrm{d}x$. The mathematicians don't really like this explanation, because it's not 100% correct, but it's much easier to remember.

Comment: @HongboMiao Sorry, my formula was wrong, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply the chain rule. Since $x(y) = y^2, x'(y) = 2y$ and
$$
\frac{d}{dy} f(x(y)) = f'(x(y)) x'(y) = 2(y^2) 2y = 4y^3.
$$